# Run an async task in Windows Phone and wait it later

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to start a Task when my Main Page is loaded, which get my position using Xamarin.Mobile in background. And the difficult point is to wait, if this task isn't finished, when the user clicked on a button.

On Xamarin iOS, I managed to do it but when I try to do exactly the same on Windows Phone 8.0 I get an AggregateException with as message : "One or more errors occurred".

There is the code i use :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Geolocation;

namespace Application.WinPhone
{
    public partial class Connexion : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        static Task w;

        // Constructor
        public Connexion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            w = new Task (() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Start");
                Geolocator geolocator = null;

                geolocator = new Geolocator() { DesiredAccuracy = 50};

                var t = geolocator.GetPositionAsync(8000).ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Latitude : {0} Longitude : {1}",       x.Result.Latitude, x.Result.Longitude)); //Visual Studio's debugger indicate this line with the exception
                });
                t.Wait();
                Debug.WriteLine("Finished");
            });
            w.Start();

        }

        private void Connexion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                w.Wait();

                //Here use the position find by the task to know on which page send the user
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Inscription.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
}
```

If there are some grammatical errors in my post Sorry i'm French. :)

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Check the `InnerException` property of your AggregateException to understand what's going on

Comment: The InnerException's message said : "A task was canceled". 

Why the task would be canceled ?

Comment: You're doing this task in the constructor, what's calling that? Perhaps it is taking too long and something is killing it?

Comment: The constructor is called by the application itself because it's the first page of the application which is define in WPAppManifest.xml I didn't find any subjects about a timeout in Windows Phone

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't do any heavy lifting in the constructor. That's a [design flaw](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). Second, Windows Phone expects your app to [start in a limited amount of time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817009(v=vs.105).aspx), i.e. 10 seconds max. So, starting the app and waiting 8 seconds on the Geolocator is probably taking too much time, hence the canceled task.

What you could do is create the Geolocator in the constructor of the page and get the position in the OnNavigatedTo event.

Comment: Unfortunately I've got the same error the task is being canceled.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you should really do is to rearange it with asnyc/await as you really don't need creating tasks in this case, i.e. (out of my head):

```
public Connexion()
{
   Connexion.IsEnabled = false;
   var ignore = InitAsync();
}
private async Task InitAsync()
{
            Debug.WriteLine("Start");
            Geolocator geolocator = null;

            geolocator = new Geolocator() { DesiredAccuracy = 50};

            var result = await geolocator.GetPositionAsync(8000);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Latitude : {0} Longitude : {1}",       result.Latitude, result.Longitude)); //Visual Studio's debugger indicate this line with the exception
            Connexion.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

Note that button should be disabled unless action succeeds. You should also add try/catch handler in there and you'll get clearer exception (perhaps Geolocator can't be created in a non UI thread?)
Besides what Geolocator class are you actually using - Forms Labs one?

Comment: You shouldn't be ignoring the task that is initializing the type.  It becomes impossible to allow the caller to actually know when the instance is safe to use, and doesn't prevent them from using the type when it's not safe to use.

Comment: In this case it can (at least for this example) - button won't be enabled unless geolocator finds the position. But in general case it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: I try your solution but I have the same problem, I didn't go beyond the line : await geolocator.GetPositionAsync(8000); 
It's the same exception : A task was canceled.

Comment: But what Geolocator are you using?

Comment: I use the geolocator provide by this component : [XamarinMobile](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile)

Comment: Did you check that
    geolocator.IsGeolocationEnabled?
Besides, cancellation exception might be due to the timeout (8s in your case).

Comment: Yes I have already checked that "IsGeolocationEnabled" is true. 
I think the same but I don't understand why GetPositionAsync will timeout in Windows Phone and not in Monotouch or Monodroid

Comment: Perhaps that device takes more time to acquire position? Can you try to increase timeout and/or test in emulator?

Comment: I have an another project which works perfectly with 10 seconds. And it's the same problem with the emulator.